# Need transfer edit.blade laravel view to Edit.vue view

Tags: php, vuejs3, laravel-blade, inertiajs, laravel-10

What I want to transfer edit.blade view to Edit.vue view:

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Редактирование записи сотрудника') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>

    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                <div class="p-6 text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100">
                    <div class="border-solid md:border-dotted rounded-full py-2 px-4">
                        <form action="{{ route('staff.update', $staff->id) }}" method="post">
                            @csrf
                            @method('PATCH')

                            <input class="mt-1" type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Фамилия" value="{{ $staff->surname }}">
                            <input class="mt-1" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя" value="{{ $staff->name }}">
                            <input class="mt-1" type="text" name="patronymic" placeholder="Отчество" value="{{ $staff->patronymic }}"><p></p>
                            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('surname', 'Неверная Фамилия')" class="inline-block mr-[90px]"/>
                            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('name', 'Неверное Имя')" class="inline-block ml-[30px]"/>
                            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('patronymic', 'Неверное Отчество')" class="inline-block ml-[140px]"/><br>
                            <input class="mt-1 w-[180px]" type="date" name="dob" placeholder="Дата рождения" title="Дата рождения" value="{{ $staff->dob }}">
                            <input class="mt-1" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Телефон" value="{{ $staff->phone }}">
                            <input class="mt-1" type="email" name="email_personal" placeholder="Е-маил" value="{{ $staff->email_personal }}"><p></p>
                            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('dob', 'Неверная Дата рождения')" class="inline-block"/>
                            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('phone', 'Неверный Телефон')" class="inline-block ml-[30px]"/>
                            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('email_personal', 'Неверный Е-Маил')" class="inline-block ml-[100px]"/><br>
                            <input class="mt-1" type="text" name="gender" placeholder="Пол" value="{{ $staff->gender }}">
                            <input class="mt-1" type="number" name="INN" placeholder="ИНН" value="{{ $staff->INN }}">
                            <input class="mt-1" type="text" name="SNILS" placeholder="Снилс" value="{{ $staff->SNILS }}"><p></p>
                            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('gender', 'Неверный Пол')" class="inline-block"/>
                            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('INN', 'Неверный ИНН')" class="inline-block ml-[150px]"/>
                            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('SNILS', 'Неверный Снилс')" class="inline-block ml-[150px]"/><br>
                            <input class="mt-1" type="text" name="polis" placeholder="Полис" value="{{ $staff->polis }}">
                            <input class="mt-1" type="text" name="passport_series" placeholder="Серия паспорта" value="{{ $staff->passport_series }}">
                            <input class="mt-1" type="text" name="passport_number" placeholder="Номер паспорта" value="{{ $staff->passport_number }}"><p></p>
                            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('polis', 'Неверный Полис')" class="inline-block mr-[140px]"/>
                            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('passport_series', 'Неверное Серия паспорта') " class="inline-block mr-[70px]"/>
                            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('passport_number', 'Неверное Номер паспорта')" class="inline-block"/><br>
                            <input class="mt-1 w-[180px]" type="date" name="date_issue" placeholder="Дата выдачи" title="Дата выдачи" value="{{ $staff->date_issue }}">
                            <input class="mt-1" type="text" name="issued_whom" placeholder="Кем выдан" value="{{ $staff->issued_whom }}">
                            <input class="mt-1" type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Комментарий" value="{{ $staff->comment }}"><p></p>
                            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('date_issue', 'Неверная Дата выдачи')" class="inline-block mr-[40px]"/>
                            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('issued_whom', 'Неверный Кем выдан ')" class="inline-block mr-[30px]"/><br>
                            <button class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded mt-3 ml-[300px]">{{ __('Подтвердить') }}</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

edit method in Controller:

```
public function edit(string $id)
    {

        $staff = Staff::find($id);
        return Inertia::render('Staff/Edit', ['staff' => $staff]);
    }
```

update method in Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        // $validated = $request->validate([
        //     'surname' => 'required|string|max:50|min:3',
        //     'name' => 'required|string|max:50|min:2',
        //     'patronymic' => 'string|max:50|nullable',
        //     'dob' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
        //     'phone' => 'required|string|max:50|min:10',
        //     'email_personal' => 'required|email|max:120|min:2',
        //     'gender' => 'required|string|max:8',
        //     'INN' => 'required|integer|min:9',
        //     'SNILS' => 'required|string|max:50|min:15',
        //     'polis' => 'required|string|max:50|min:10',
        //     'passport_series' => 'required|integer|min:3',
        //     'passport_number' => 'required|integer|min:5',
        //     'date_issue' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
        //     'issued_whom' => 'required|string|max:512',
        //     'comment' => 'string|max:512|nullable',
        // ]);

        $staff = Staff::find($id);
        $staff->surname = $request->input('surname');
        $staff->name = $request->input('name');
        $staff->patronymic = $request->input('patronymic');
        $staff->dob = $request->input('dob');
        $staff->phone = $request->input('phone');
        $staff->email_personal = $request->input('email_personal');
        $staff->gender = $request->input('gender');
        $staff->INN = $request->input('INN');
        $staff->SNILS = $request->input('SNILS');
        $staff->polis = $request->input('polis');
        $staff->passport_series = $request->input('passport_series');
        $staff->passport_number = $request->input('passport_number');
        $staff->date_issue = $request->input('date_issue');
        $staff->issued_whom = $request->input('issued_whom');
        $staff->comment = $request->input('comment');
        $staff->update();

        return redirect()->route('staff.index')->withSuccess('Успешно обновлено.');


    }
```

I tried release it in my vue view but it don't work(i click on button, but it doesn't worked).

What I tried in my Edit.vue view:

```
<script setup>
import AppLayout from '@/Layouts/AppLayout.vue';
import Welcome from '@/Components/Welcome.vue';
import { useAttrs } from 'vue';
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import PrimaryButton from '@/Components/PrimaryButton.vue';
import TextInput from '@/Components/TextInput.vue';

const staff = defineProps({ staff: Object})

const form = useForm({
    surname: '',
    name: '',
    patronymic: '',
    dob: '',
    phone: '',
    email_personal: '',
    gender: '',
    INN: '',
    SNILS: '',
    polis: '',
    passport_series: '',
    passport_number: '',
    date_issue: '',
    issued_whom: '',
    comment: '',
});

const submit = () => {
    form.transform(data => ({
        ...data, 
    })).patch(route('staff.update', $id = staff.id))
};

</script>

<template>
    <AppLayout title="Staff">
        <template #header>
            <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
                Создание сотрудника
            </h2>
        </template>

        <div class="py-12">
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                    <div class="p-6 text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100">
                        <div class="border-solid md:border-dotted rounded-full py-2 px-4">
                            <form v-on:submit.prevent="submit" action="{{ route('staff.store') }}" method="post">
                                <TextInput class="mt-1" type="text" id="surname" placeholder="Фамилия" v-model="form.surname"/>
                                <TextInput class="mt-1" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Имя" v-model="form.name"/>
                                <TextInput class="mt-1" type="text" id="patronymic" placeholder="Отчество" v-model="form.patronymic"/><p></p>
                                <TextInput class="mt-1 w-[180px]" type="date" id="dob" placeholder="Дата рождения" title="Дата рождения" v-model="form.dob"/>
                                <TextInput class="mt-1" type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Телефон" v-model="form.phone"/>
                                <TextInput class="mt-1" type="email" id="email_personal" placeholder="Е-маил" v-model="form.email_personal"/><p></p>
                                <TextInput class="mt-1" type="text" id="gender" placeholder="Пол" v-model="form.gender"/>
                                <TextInput class="mt-1" type="number" id="INN" placeholder="ИНН" v-model="form.INN"/>
                                <TextInput class="mt-1" type="text" id="SNILS" placeholder="Снилс" v-model="form.SNILS"/><p></p>
                                <TextInput class="mt-1" type="text" id="polis" placeholder="Полис" v-model="form.polis"/>
                                <TextInput class="mt-1" type="text" id="passport_series" placeholder="Серия паспорта" v-model="form.passport_series"/>
                                <TextInput class="mt-1" type="text" id="passport_number" placeholder="Номер паспорта" v-model="form.passport_number"/><p></p>
                                <TextInput class="mt-1 w-[180px]" type="date" id="date_issue" placeholder="Дата выдачи" title="Дата выдачи" v-model="form.date_issue"/>
                                <TextInput class="mt-1" type="text" id="issued_whom" placeholder="Кем выдан" v-model="form.issued_whom"/>
                                <TextInput class="mt-1" type="text" id="comment" placeholder="Комментарий" v-model="form.comment"/><p></p>
                                <div>
                                    <!-- Название элемента input определяет имя в массиве $_FILES -->
                                    Прикрепить фото:<br><br> <input class="file:bg-gradient-to-b file:from-blue-500 file:to-blue-600 file:px-10 file:py-3 file:m-5 file:border-none file:rounded-full file:text-white file:cursor-pointer file:shadow-lg file:shadow-blue-600/50 bg-gradient-to-br from-gray-700 text-white/80 rounded-full cursor-pointer shadow-xl shadow-gray-700/60 " id="userfile" type="file" /><br><br>
                                </div><br>
                                <PrimaryButton type="submit" class="ms-4" :class="{ 'opacity-25': form.processing }" :disabled="form.processing">
                                    Далее
                                </PrimaryButton>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </AppLayout>
</template>
```

If you want to see another file code comment this post please! Thank you.